# What is the @macro annotation in Flutter and Dart documentation

Tags: flutter, dart, documentation

When I'm reading the source code I often see something like this (from [TextField](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart)):

```dart
/// {@macro flutter.widgets.editableText.keyboardType}
final TextInputType keyboardType;
```

What does the `@macro` mean?

*I found the answer so I'm posting it below as a self-answer Q&A.*

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A `@macro` is a way to insert some [dartdoc](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc) documentation that has been written somewhere else. That way you don't have duplicate docs that you have to maintain.

The string that follows `@macro` is the name of a template, which includes the documentation you'll insert. So in the [TextField](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart) example:

```dart
/// {@macro flutter.widgets.editableText.keyboardType}
final TextInputType keyboardType;
```

the template name is `flutter.widgets.editableText.keyboardType`. If you go to the source code for [EditableText](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart), you'll find the template with it's documentation text:

```dart
/// {@template flutter.widgets.editableText.keyboardType}
/// The type of keyboard to use for editing the text.
///
/// Defaults to [TextInputType.text] if [maxLines] is one and
/// [TextInputType.multiline] otherwise.
/// {@endtemplate}
final TextInputType keyboardType;
```

The annotation `@template` starts the template and is followed by its name. `@endtemplate` finishes it.

When you view the documentation for `EditableText.keyboardType` and `TextField.keyboardType`, you can see they are exactly the same:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/EditableText/keyboardType.html
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/keyboardType.html

Read more in the [dartdoc documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc).

Comment: I've searched for something like this recently but now I found it by coincidence. is there some documentation about all of this magic stuff?

Comment: @Adnan, there is a bit in that last link I included.

Comment: Is there a way to insert a doc that is without a template name? @Suragch

Comment: @davidn, I'm not sure how to do that.