# dart show documentation from another method in another file

Tags: dart, dartdoc

Is it possible to show the documentation of a function in the documentation of another function residing in a different file? Macros are only valid in their own file.

In the Flutter source code, they use something like this, but it does not seem to have any effect:

```dart
/// {@macro flutter.widgets.editableText.keyboardType}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Macro docs** is what you are looking for. They are already [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602658/what-is-the-macro-annotation-in-flutter-and-dart-documentation) but in summary allows you do exactly what you want: copy a documentation from a place to somewhere else without re-write.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is link to the referenced function.

`file_a.dart`

```dart
/// Also see [functionB].
void functionA() {}
```

`file_b.dart`

```dart
/// Another function.
void functionB() {}
```

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#documentation-comments